# Layered application and inter layer communication

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am designing a service which has multiple layers.(To be precise 5 layers).

Design rules:

> Each layer can only talk to the immediate layer beneath it.
>
> Communication between two of them would be asynchronous.
>
> Data Flow would be bottom up, that is when data arrives at the lower
>     layers,the upper layers get notifications.

Subject-Observer pattern comes to my mind but I feel this tightly couples the two layers.

Is there anything that I can do with signal/slots mechanism .I havent worked on it but boost does give something similar, I guess.

Has anybody come across this problem/are there any better design solutions??

Comment: How is it that you have decided to have five layers when you don't yet know how they will communicate?  What is the purpose of this service?

Comment: layers here are based on the functionalities to be carried out...bottom most layer deals with hardware abstraction,layer just above that  deals with data interpretation and so on..

Comment: it runs on a wearable platform(arm)

Comment: "are there any better design solutions" Yes, put the higher layers into control as much as possible. Write libraries, not frameworks (which your lower levels are if they take control). I know this is very generic (which is why it isn't an answer, but a comment) but details depend on your actual issue and on the circumstances of the hardware you're working with.